Synchronous vue components rendering into a string
There is a SFC named Bubble of vue, that contains some simple layout.
Bubble.vue
<script setup lang="ts">

</script>

<template>
  <div hinted-name="wrapper-bubble" class="hinted-bubble-wrapper">
    <div class="hinted-bubble-frame" hinted-name="frame"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="stylus">

</style>

I also have a class that uses this layout as a base for logic.
export class BubbleStepView extends StepComponentView {
  constructor() {
    super(Bubble.toString);
  }
}

This class needs to receive only an HTML string as a super argument.
Could someone tell me if there's any way to synchronously convert a Vue component into a string?
The application works on a browser.
I attempted to use the method described in https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/rendertostring.html, but it didn't work for me because it returns a Promise.

This isn't regular use for Vue. Consider explaining your case, this looks like XY problem that's supposed to be solved in more conventional way

yea, for me using vue does not seem appropriates, however i need to understand it in order to prove to my team. And take another technology in the future

The use of vue as template engine is not justified because this discards almost all functionality of the framework while containing all the overhead, any dedicated engine like Nunjucks would be far more superior. Consider updating the question with full details regarding your case including the implementation and usage of BubbleStepView if you're interested in best possible solution

You should render the component:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>
import { getCurrentInstance, h, render as renderVue } from 'vue';
import Bubble from './Bubble.vue';

const self = getCurrentInstance();
const div = document.createElement('div');
const vNode = h(Bubble);
vNode.appContext = self.appContext;
renderVue(vNode, div);
const html = div.innerHTML;
div.remove();
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ html }}</div>
</template>

You can even watch HTML without knowing dependencies:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref, reactive, watch } from 'vue';
import Bubble from './Bubble.vue';
const html = ref();
const $cont = ref();
const content = ref('type me');
onMounted(()=>{
  html.value = $cont.value.innerHTML;
  new MutationObserver(()=>{
    html.value = $cont.value.innerHTML;
  }).observe($cont.value, {childList:true, subtree:true, attributes:true, characterData:true});
});

</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="content">
  <div ref="$cont" key="1" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;width:0;height:0">
    <bubble>{{ content }}</bubble>
  </div>
  <div>{{ html }}</div>
</template>


It looks like a workaround, isn't?

@VladislavUtkin I use it all time to render a component into a random DOM element on a HTML page, for me it looks ok. Vue uses VDOM, so there's no HTML in a component, only a render function, so render it and grab HTML, seems easy

@VladislavUtkin https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism . i guess if you read all vue docs you wouldn't ask your question in the first place...

ASAP, however i'd like to see other answers if you don't mind.

@VladislavUtkin added some dynamic example, just to show what could be done in some cases where HTML of a rendered component is needed

@AlexanderNenashev Yes, it is the workaround. A proper way would be to delegate this part of view to vue app. Even if you need to integrate it to non-vue app, which is common, use container element as is and attach it to dom instead of trying to get non-reactive html representation

@EstusFlask i ve demonstrated that in the second code snippet

@AlexanderNenashev Sorry, I meant to tag the OP in the previous comment. This becomes a hack at this point, rarely ever needed unless you have to tamper with someone else's app. Considering that the changes in DOM output matter and not just static html output, I'd expect it's possible to pass  $cont.value element as is where it's consumed with few or no changes made to that part of code

@EstusFlask i would say watching variables that the component depends on is better than watch HTML mutation to get an updated HTML, but MutationObserver helped in one case where I didn't want to be depended on the variables. I found that very cool, agnostic. Yes, it's a hack but when you need to get a job done fast and close a task that could be a reliable temporary measure

@EstusFlask it was case when i watch mutations in HTML and call a jQuery plugin to update itself ‍♂️
